# Rails 4 mixed singleton and plural resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton

I have the following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to expose two URLs for profiles:

```
/profile  # edit the profile of the logged in user
/profiles/:id  # view the profile of user :id
```

It seems like I'm going to have to do a fair amount of customization to my controllers and views for a situation that should be fairly common.  Is there a standard way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expose these two routes:

```
get '/profile', to: 'users#edit_current_user'
get '/profiles/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

Each action should do what you want in the controller method.